# Why would I want to integrate CSS into JavaScript?

Tags: django, webpack

I've been tasked with converting the static asset management for a Django project to webpack (it currently uses [django pipeline](https://django-pipeline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)).

I got the JavaScript done no problem, then moved onto the SASS files, using [sass-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader), which to my horror seems to want to convert the CSS into JavaScript, which is apparently a thing these days.

Questions:

1. Why would I want to do this?
2. Is it worthwhile doing on a django project?
3. What needs to change in the HTML templates for this to work?
4. Are there any Django plugins which help with this?

EDIT:

Apparently it is `css-loader` which converts .css to js not `sass-loader`, but if I comment that out like below:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {test: /\.(js|es6)$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" },
    {test: /\.css$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "raw-loader"},
    {
      test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
      use: [
        //"css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
        "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS, using Node Sass by default
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I get:

> ```
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:4)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> ```

So can I, or can I not, use sass-loader just to compile sass to css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is `css-loader` which converts `.css` to `js` not `sass-loader`. [Check first three lines in sass-loader readme](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader).

I'm frontend developer so I can answer only for your first question:

1. Why convert `css` to `js`?

   - you can use relative path (otherwise you have to keep in mind how your project will be structured after compilation).
   - you can import name of classes and attach hash to it. In such case you can reuse class names such `.box` `.container` etc. without fear to mess something in your styles because in compiled version they would look like `.box-h12f2` from one file and `.box-aeg2` from another.
   - you can import values from your css to js. Some libraries can customize colors, but they do it inside js. Usually you want to have single source of truth, in order to  change styles easily in one place for whole project.

try this config (with src/styles.scss file)

```
const
    path = require('path'),
    webpack = require('webpack'),
    MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const srcFolder = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

const miniCssExtractPlugin = new MiniCssExtractPlugin();

const config = {
    resolve: {
        modules: [ srcFolder, 'node_modules', ],
        extensions: [ '.js', ],
    },

    entry: [
       path.resolve(srcFolder, 'styles.scss'),
    ],

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    },

    module: {

        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ],
            }

        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        miniCssExtractPlugin
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question a bit, as from reading your answer I'm now not sure whether I'm using sass-loader correctly.

Comment: Actually [sass loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader) is for webpack are you sure it is right to use it for django pipeline?

Comment: We are replacing django-pipeline with webpack.

Comment: Ok I checked there is no easy way to conver sass to css. So probably you have to use css loader. I have added webpack.config example above so you can try and use it for your scss files